# What Alternatives are there to AJAX Control Toolkits ValidationCallOutExtender

Tags: jquery, telerik, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am having issues with the Calloutextender in Chrome.  If an error occurs on an element on the page which is not in view, The callout extender positions itself at the top of the viewport. That is it does not set focus on the element and move the browser caret and view to focus on the element in error. When working, this would usually see focus set on the element in error and the callout displayed correctly.

Do telerik do one? I know there is a JQuery alternative, but is it any good (can I target just target specific elements)

Thanks.

Comment: I was orignially asking the question as the Callout was failing in Chrome.  This can be fixed by getting the latest release of the Ajax Control Toolkit....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have collated information I have found from a number of different sources to help as quickly as possible.....

So, if the the AJAX control toolkit is failing you, consider upgrading to the April 2010 release. Be aware that upgrading, though, can be a bit painful.

Right then,  I am using Telerik controls in a .NET 3.5 environment and this has meant I have had to go with the following solution here (and it works!!):

(scroll to Rowland O'connor about half way down) 
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/ajax-control-toolkit-compatability.aspx
(in essence in the RadScriptManager, Telerik's overriden ScriptManager - we explcitly refer to specific versions of ACT js files)

However, if you have different set up (.NET 4, non-Telerik solution) check out this link

http://blog.thinkoriginally.com/2010/05/03/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-ajaxcontroltoolkit-requires-asp-net-ajax-4-0-scripts/

HTH